# Buy 2 specific products and get one specific product free

Tags: coupon

been trying to set this up but need some guidance, we are running an offer where if the customers add products X and Z to the cart product Y will be free of charge. Is this possible via the build in system in Magento or do I need a extension for this?

Magento version: 1.9.2.1

Comment: This example shows how to set up a shopping cart price rule for a “Buy X, Get Y Free” promotion. The format of the discount is as follows: http://goo.gl/4uLPGW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the admin section go to **Promotions > Shopping Cart Rules**

[image: Shopping cart rules]

Fill in the basic rule information.

Go to the tab "Conditions"
Add a new rule with the following conditions.
You have to do this for both products x and z:
1. Click the + sign and pick the option "Product Attribute Combination". 
2. Then below the text "If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: " add a sub condition and choose the option "SKU", 
3. Select the product X, for the second one product Z.

[image: conditions]
Go to the tab Actions 
Set Discount Amount to 100
Make sure "Apply" is "Percent of the product price discount"

In the section "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions"
Add a new condition with option "SKU" and select the SKU via the chooser of product Y. Save the rule.

Now the product will be free when a user is buying product X AND Z.

[image: actions]

Comment: If you prefer third-party solutions for this kind of conditions, I suggest using the Special Promotions Pro (goo.gl/jYPgcS) from Amasty.

Comment: This answer isn't working for me....

Comment: In above Promotion, need to add qty restriction on Action Tab, otherwise while buying X and Z product, Free Product can be availed in multiple quantities, which should avoided and not recommended most of time.

Lets say, Product X, Z and Free all having same Price, $100 each. 
Now customer buys 1 Quantity of Product X, 1 Quantity of Product Z, and 5 Quantities of Free Product.

In above case, amount is charged of X and Z products only. and Customer get N quantities without paying additional (as there is no qty restriction in Action tab).