# Magento buy 2 get one free

Tags: magento-1.9

I followed this 
[Buy 2 specific products and get one specific product free](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/buy-2-specific-products-and-get-one-specific-product-free)

But the promotion is not working, when that particualr sku is added to cart the free sku is not added in the cart. The details are given below.

**Condition Tab:**

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is one of  sku047, sku030

Quantity in cart  is  2

**Action Tab:**

Apply Percent of the product price discount

Discount Amount *

100
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 0

Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 0

Apply to Shipping Amount no

Free Shipping no

Stop Further Rules Processing no

Gift SKU

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is  sku027

Comment: Please try with http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html

Comment: It didn't really change anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Adding free product as gift]

So I changed the Percent of the product price discount to add a gift and added the free product's sku in gift sku field. After that whenever some added 2 of a certain product in the cart a third certain product is added as free!

**NOTE:** condition tab is the same as above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the link you provided. ([Buy 2 specific products and get one specific product free](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/buy-2-specific-products-and-get-one-specific-product-free)) It gives the third item free if and only if all 3 products are in the cart. And the solution provided by link is working fine.

If you are using coupon then apply coupon else it will automatically deduce the price.

Comment: Which version did you try that on?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1